# Hadoop use one instance for each mapper

Tags: java, hadoop, static, mapreduce, mapper

I'm using Hadoop 's map reduce to parse xml files. So I have a class called `Parser` that can have a method `parse()` to parse the xml files. And So I should use it in the Mapper's `map()` function.

However it means that every time, when I want to call a `Parser`, I need to create a `Parser` instance. But this instance should be the same for each map job. So I'm wondering if I can just instantize this `Parser` just once?

And just another add-on question, why the `Mapper` class is always static?

Comment: In a distributed computing environment, sharing instances of a variable isn't possible... Also not sure if the Mapper is always static. Where do you see that?

Comment: Scratch that second statement... I haven't written mapreduce recently, but here's the explanation  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570674/why-declaring-mapper-and-reducer-classes-as-static

Comment: In this example code, the Mapper is static class. [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html)

Comment: +1 cricket_007. Need not be static(except its inner class). above link by cricket_007 describes "When declaring mapper and reducer classes as inner classes to another class, they have to be declared static such that they are not dependent on the parent class." @Yilinkg Liu : In your example also your class WordCount2 is driver where all other classes were nested.  Isnt it ?

Comment: updated my answer. pls check it

Comment: The Mapper and Reducer need to be static unless they are nested in the driver program primarily because the `main` method is static. I was correct that they are not always static, as-in, you can write `MyMapper.java`, `MyReducer.java`, and `MyDriver.java`, and non of those contain static classes.

Comment: Answer was helpful to sign-off this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure one parser instance per Mapper , please use mappers setup method for instantiating your parser instance and clean using cleanup method.

Same thing we applied for protobuf parser which we had, but need to make sure that your parser instance is thread safe, and no shared data.
Note :  setup and cleanup method will be called only once per mapper so we can initialize private variables there.
To clarify what cricket_007 said in ***"In a distributed computing environment, sharing instances of a variable isn't possible..."***

[we have a practice of reusing of writable classes instead of creating new writables every time we need. we can instantiate once and re-set the writable multiple times as described by Tip 6](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/12/7-tips-for-improving-mapreduce-performance/)
Similarly parser objects also can be re-used(Tip-6 style). as described in below code.
For ex :

```
private YourXMLParser xmlParser = null;
    @Override
        protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            super.setup(context);
            xmlParser= new YourXMLParser();        
        }

     @Override
        protected void cleanup(Mapper<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result, NullWritable, Put>.Context context) throws IOException,
                        InterruptedException {
            super.cleanup(context);
                  xmlParser= null;
    }
```