# MapReduce with rewrited fileInputFormat can't output the result

Tags: java, hadoop, file-io, mapreduce

I just in learning  hadoop  recently(I use hadoop2.7.3 &java 1.7.0.89 ) . I write some codes to analysis different TV broadcast & comments on different websites.  I  rewrite  the filesinputformat class. but  when   I run  my codes on eclipse.there has a lot of exception . I  try  to debug on eclipse. just find find the mapper  or  reducer has some problem.. But I'm not sure what went wrong..

here  is  the date  examples ,  the  secondary data   is the nickname  of  website

```
truelove    3   3678    0   0   0   1
truelove    2   39155   0   0   173 438
truelove    1   142208  1   2   1   1
truelove    1   142208  1   2   1   1
truelove    1   142208  1   2   1   1
frink   2   950 0   0   0   0
frink   2   800 0   0   0   0
daughter    4   4489850 0   0   0   0
daughter    4   1161    0   0   0   0
princess    2   33593   0   0   0   3
princess    2   36118   0   0   0   2
princess    2   38608   0   0   0   1
princess    3   2542    0   0   0   0
princess    1   35322   2   4   0   1
```

and  then I rewrite the inputformat

The custom data formats

```
      package com.hadoop.mapreduce;

    import java.io.DataInput;
    import java.io.DataOutput;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;


    /*1-5means：1youku2souhu3tudou4aiqiyi5xunlei
   princess 2   33593   0   0   0   3
    princess    2   36118   0   0   0   2
    princess    2   38608   0   0   0   1
    princess    3   2542    0   0   0   0
    princess    1   35322   2   4   0   1*/
    public  class TVplaydata implements WritableComparable<Object>{
        //private String tvname;

        private int tvplaynum;
        private int tvfavorite;
        private int tvcomment;
        private int tvdown;
        private int tvvote;
    public TVplaydata(){}
    public void set(int tvplaynum,int tvfavorite,int tvcomment,int tvdown,int tvvote){
        this.tvplaynum = tvplaynum;
        this.tvfavorite = tvfavorite;
        this.tvcomment = tvcomment;
        this.tvdown = tvdown;
        this.tvvote = tvvote;
    }
    //source  get  set  
    public void setTvpalynum(int tvplaynum) {
        this.tvplaynum = tvplaynum;
    }
    public int getTvpalynum() {
        return tvplaynum;

    }

    public int getTvfavorite() {
        return tvfavorite;
    }
    public void setTvfavorite(int tvfavorite) {
        this.tvfavorite = tvfavorite;
    }
    public int getTvcomment() {
        return tvcomment;
    }
    public void setTvcomment(int tvcomment) {
        this.tvcomment = tvcomment;
    }
    public int getTvdown() {
        return tvdown;
    }
    public void setTvdown(int tvdown) {
        this.tvdown = tvdown;
    }
    public int getTvvote() {
        return tvvote;
    }
    public void setTvvote(int tvvote) {
        this.tvvote = tvvote;
    }
        @Override

        public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tvplaynum = in.readInt();
            tvfavorite = in.readInt();
            tvcomment = in.readInt();
            tvdown = in.readInt();
            tvvote = in.readInt();
        }

        @Override

        public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            out.writeInt(tvplaynum);
            out.writeInt(tvfavorite);
            out.writeInt(tvcomment);
            out.writeInt(tvdown);
            out.writeInt(tvvote);
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object o) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

then  rewrite  the inputformat.

```
package com.hadoop.mapreduce;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader;



 class PlayinputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Text, TVplaydata>{

    @Override
    public RecordReader<Text, TVplaydata> createRecordReader(InputSplit input, TaskAttemptContext context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return new TvplayRecordReader();
    }
    class TvplayRecordReader  extends RecordReader<Text, TVplaydata>{

        public LineReader in;  
        public Text lineKey; 
        public TVplaydata lineValue;
        public Text line;

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(in !=null){
                in.close();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Text getCurrentKey() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return lineKey;
        }

        @Override
        public TVplaydata getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return lineValue;
        }

        @Override
        public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(InputSplit input, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FileSplit split=(FileSplit)input;  
            Configuration job=context.getConfiguration();  
            Path file=split.getPath();  
            FileSystem fs=file.getFileSystem(job);  

            FSDataInputStream filein=fs.open(file); //open
            in=new LineReader(filein,job); 
            line=new Text();  
            lineKey=new Text(); 
            lineValue = new TVplaydata();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int linesize=in.readLine(line); 
            if(linesize==0)  return false; 

            String[] pieces = line.toString().split("\t"); 
            if(pieces.length != 7){  
                throw new IOException("Invalid record received");  
            }


            lineKey.set(pieces[0]+"\t"+pieces[1]);
            lineValue.set(Integer.parseInt(pieces[2]),Integer.parseInt(pieces[3]),Integer.parseInt(pieces[4])
                    ,Integer.parseInt(pieces[5]),Integer.parseInt(pieces[6]));
            return true;
        }
    }
 }
```

at last   write  the  main  method  to run Mapper&Reducer

```
package com.hadoop.mapreduce;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;



public class TVPlay extends Configured implements Tool{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] paths = {"hdfs://wang:9000/mapreduce/tvplay.txt","hdfs://wang:9000/mapreduce/tvout"};
    int ec = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new TVPlay(), paths);
    System.exit(ec);
}


        //mapper
public class TVmapper extends Mapper<Text, TVplaydata, Text, TVplaydata> {
    public void map(Text key,TVplaydata value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                context.write(key, value);
            }
        }
public class TVreducer extends Reducer<Text, TVplaydata, Text, Text>{   
            private Text m_key = new Text();
            private Text m_value = new Text();
            private MultipleOutputs<Text, Text> mos;
            protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
                    InterruptedException {
                mos = new MultipleOutputs<Text, Text>(context);
            }
        public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<TVplaydata> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

                int tvplaynum = 0;
                int tvfavorite = 0;
                int tvcomment = 0;
                int tvvote = 0;
                int tvdown = 0;
            for (TVplaydata tv:values) {
                tvplaynum += tv.getTvpalynum();
                tvfavorite += tv.getTvfavorite();
                tvcomment += tv.getTvcomment();
                tvvote += tv.getTvvote();
                tvdown += tv.getTvdown();
                }

            String[] records = key.toString().split("\t");

            String source  = records[1];
            m_key.set(records[0]);
            m_value.set(tvplaynum+"\t"+tvfavorite+"\t"+tvcomment+"\t"+tvdown+"\t"+tvvote);

            if(source.equals("1")){
                mos.write("youku", m_key, m_value);
            }else if (source.equals("2")) {
                mos.write("souhu", m_key, m_value);
            }else if (source.equals("3")) {
                mos.write("tudou",m_key, m_value);
            }else if (source.equals("4")) {
                mos.write("aiqiyi", m_key, m_value);
            }else if (source.equals("5")) {
                mos.write("xunlei", m_key, m_value);
            }else{
                mos.write("other", m_key, m_value);
            }
        }
        protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException ,InterruptedException{
                mos.close();
        }   
        }

        @Override
        public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();

            Path path = new Path(arg0[1]);
            FileSystem hdfs = path.getFileSystem(conf);
            if(hdfs.isDirectory(path)){
                hdfs.delete(path, true);
            }
            Job job = new Job(conf,"tvplay");
            job.setJarByClass(TVPlay.class);
            // set InputFormatClass 
            job.setInputFormatClass(PlayinputFormat.class);
            //  set  mapper
            job.setMapperClass(TVmapper.class);
            job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setMapOutputValueClass(TVplaydata.class);
            // set  reduce
            job.setReducerClass(TVreducer.class);
            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(arg0[0]));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(arg0[1]));
            MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "youku", TextOutputFormat.class,
                    Text.class, Text.class);
            MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "souhu", TextOutputFormat.class,
                    Text.class, Text.class);
            MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "tudou", TextOutputFormat.class,
                    Text.class, Text.class);
            MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "aiqiyi", TextOutputFormat.class,
                    Text.class, Text.class);
            MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "xunlei", TextOutputFormat.class,
                    Text.class, Text.class);
            MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "other", TextOutputFormat.class,
                    Text.class, Text.class);

            return job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1;
        }
}
```

Here  is  the exceptions

```
2017-06-20 23:03:26,848 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation] - session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2017-06-20 23:03:26,854 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics] - Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
2017-06-20 23:03:27,874 WARN [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader] - Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
2017-06-20 23:03:28,186 WARN [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader] - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2017-06-20 23:03:28,236 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat] - Total input paths to process : 1
2017-06-20 23:03:28,639 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter] - number of splits:1
2017-06-20 23:03:29,389 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter] - Submitting tokens for job: job_local622257889_0001
2017-06-20 23:03:30,552 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job] - The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
2017-06-20 23:03:30,556 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job] - Running job: job_local622257889_0001
2017-06-20 23:03:30,607 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner] - OutputCommitter set in config null
2017-06-20 23:03:30,630 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter] - File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
2017-06-20 23:03:30,670 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner] - OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
2017-06-20 23:03:31,562 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job] - Job job_local622257889_0001 running in uber mode : false
2017-06-20 23:03:31,567 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job] -  map 0% reduce 0%
2017-06-20 23:03:31,569 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner] - Waiting for map tasks
2017-06-20 23:03:31,571 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner] - Starting task: attempt_local622257889_0001_m_000000_0
2017-06-20 23:03:31,667 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter] - File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
2017-06-20 23:03:31,691 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree] - ProcfsBasedProcessTree currently is supported only on Linux.
2017-06-20 23:03:34,256 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task] -  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.WindowsBasedProcessTree@26cd629f
2017-06-20 23:03:34,259 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner] - map task executor complete.
2017-06-20 23:03:34,485 WARN [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner] - job_local622257889_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.hadoop.mapreduce.TVPlay$TVmapper.<init>()
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.hadoop.mapreduce.TVPlay$TVmapper.<init>()
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.hadoop.mapreduce.TVPlay$TVmapper.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:128)
    ... 8 more
2017-06-20 23:03:34,574 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job] - Job job_local622257889_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
2017-06-20 23:03:34,598 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job] - Counters: 0
```

I have no idea what this means . Thinks for your help!

Comment: Can you also show command you used to run MR job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AT last  I find  the  mapper  &reducer are not **static** methods. when  I change them to static methods .it will be OK.

[Why declaring Mapper and Reducer classes as static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570674/why-declaring-mapper-and-reducer-classes-as-static)

Hadoop uses reflection to create an instance of the class for each map or reduce task that runs. The new instance created expects a zero argument constructor (otherwise how would it know what to pass).

By declaring the inner mapper or reduce class without the static keyword, the java compile actually creates a constructor which expects an instance of the parent class to be passed in at construction.

You should be able to see this by running the javap command against the generated classfile

Also, the static keyword is not valid when used in a parent class declaration (which is why you never see it at the top level, but only in the child classes)

Answer (score 0):

You've put the job configuration in the `run()` method of the reducer, which is wrong. The easiest solution is to move all of this code into the `main()` method of `TVplay`.

Unless you are clear on what you're doing, you shouldnt generally be overriding the `run()` method, so i would completely remove this from the reduce class.